# Has the Episcopal Church ever identified "patriarchy" as a sin?

Tags: sin, episcopal

I was listening to a Minnesota Public Radio program entitled "[Female faith leaders preach #SilenceIsNotSpiritual](https://www.mprnews.org/story/2018/02/21/female-faith-leaders-preach-silence-is-not-spiritual)" (Feb 21, 2018). One of the guest speakers was author [Rachel Held Evans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_Held_Evans), who is an Episcopal. During her discussion, she said this (emphasis mine):

> Something that's been especially meaningful to me has been revisiting those stories of the women from scripture who were the victims of—what are sometimes called the "texts of terror"—the stories of rape or violence against women or, you know, assault against women.
>
> And using those as a way to honor them and to honor the women who continue to be victims of patriarchy and violence against women. And to sort of memorialize them and also to let their stories be a reminder that we…for how long **the sin of patriarchy** and violence against women and the subjugation of women has been a part of our human story […]

Has the Episcopal church ever identified "patriarchy" as a sin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears not, however they do list it as a ["Central question" in sexual ethics:](https://www.episcopalchurch.org/library/glossary/sexual-ethics)

> Central questions in sexual ethics now include the nature of sexuality, sexual orientation, sexual identity, and gender identity; the historic and social diversity of sexual practices and relationships; and **the effects of patriarchy and the need for justice, equality, and intimacy.**

So, they acknowledge that patriarchy does exist, and they mention it in the context of the need for justice and equality, but stop short of calling it a sin.

Comment: This was an excellent first answer complete with citation.  Thank you!